# What is THREE.DirectGeometry?

Tags: three.js

The only thing i could find is:

> DirectGeometry is an internal class that you generally should not be messing with

and that it used to be called "DynamicGeometry" a while ago?

I mess with a lot of internals of three.js, like make my own shaders, extend the library, make custom buffer geometries etc.

What i understand is `THREE.Geometry` gives me a lot of structure that's easy to navigate which comes at a performance cost. Also needs to be converted to buferr geometry at some point. On the opposite end of the spectrum, i have a `THREE.BufferGeometry` that i can assemble out of `THREE.BufferAttributes` which in turn use typed arrays.

Where does direct geometry fit?

Answer (score 5):

`DirectGeometry` is a class internal to the three.js library and is used as temporary storage to convert an object of type `Geometry` to an object of type `BufferGeometry`.

I see no reason why you would be using `DirectGeometry` at the application layer.

three.js r.79

Comment: `Geometry.merge` didn't work at all for a few versions i believe, while searching for a fix or a clue i encountered DirectGeometry. 

I'm not sure what you mean by the application layer comment. I customize three.js to suit my needs, and most of it happens in these internal classes. 

Due to my inexperience i'm not sure how to go on about this. Jquery has all the source commented, that makes sense. Three doesn't so i search through the issues and pull requests in the repository.

Comment: I did find something about DirectGeometry being used for geometry i want to change, but now i can't find it.

Comment: I can't figure out why it's being used in `updateFromObject` and i believe i have  a good understanding of both BufferGeometry and Geometry :(

any help would be appreiated. Why is temporary storage needed, why is it needed in its own class, etc etc. Does it still have anything to do with dynamic?

Comment: It also seems that other's don't understand this so well either?

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/9359

A few months ago i had this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069799/three-js-loading-meshes-as-a-proxy

And i've done the exact same hack `_bufferGeoemetry.fromGeometry( geom )`. If there is a `high level A` and a `low level B` i can make those two work perfectly fine manually. When i rely on the library and it uses something obscure in the middle, this thing fails, and it seems it has been failing for months? A very brief why something is there could help :)